# How do SAN Certs degrade performance?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I have heard that when lots of names get added to a single SAN Cert (Subject Alternative Name) performance starts to degrade.

Can someone explain how SAN certs are processed so I understand what causes the performance cost as names on the SAN increases?

Comment: This might also be useful on security.se...

Comment: I've never heard of SAN entries degrading performance (other than the obvious slight increase in bandwidth to transfer the cert, and overhead of processing each entry; those shouldn't amount to anything worth mentioning unless you're trying to put millions of SANs in the same cert). Care to disclose your reference?

Comment: On a call with Comodo they told us this was the case (starts to degrade over a hundred or so). I was guessing it was maybe "processing each entry", but I'm not sure of the processing flow there -- hence my question.

Comment: It's just a `for` loop, to see if the host matches one of the SANs. 50 SANs, no problem. 5,000,000 SANs, problem.

Comment: Sounds like a ploy to get customers to buy more certificates instead to me. Do you actually have a use case for that many 'SAN'S? I've only really used it for the ability to use www/no www, and for exchange servers where i've had the external url, the internal server address and autodiscover. I can't see any SSL provider being happy providing a cert that covers 100's of names. A wildcard would be easier but that doesn't cover names with 'more dots'.

Comment: @USDMatt They usually charge extra for the SANs, so it shouldn't matter to them either way (a wildcard is commonly cheaper than a many-SAN cert too).

Comment: Guys, please remember when downvoting a question to leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: I'm testing some self-signed SANs now, can't get a measurable difference with HAProxy as the server and CURL/WGET as the clients with 2.5k names. Tried 20k names but got `(35) error:1408E098:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_MESSAGE:excessive message size`

Comment: @PeterGrace [Is it now discouraged to ask for reasons for downvotes as a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74559)

Answer (score 6):

Some superficial testing does seem to suggest that I am being fed a bunch of malarky.

I generated the cert like so:

```
openssl genrsa -out www.domain.tld.key 2048

[kbrandt@alpine: ~/sancrt] openssl req -new -key www.domain.tld.key -out www.domain.tld.csr
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:NY
Locality Name (eg, city) []:New York
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:LOTA-SAN
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:SANSRUS
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:www.domain.tld
Email Address []:kyle@SANRUS.com
....

echo -n "subjectAltName=DNS:www.domain.tld," > www.domain.tld.cnf;for i in {1..2500}; do echo -n "DNS:www$i.domain.tld,"; done >> www.domain.tld.cnf   

#manually delete comma at the end of the .cnf

openssl x509 -req -days 365 \
>   -in www.domain.tld.csr \
>   -signkey www.domain.tld.key \
>   -text \
>   -extfile  www.domain.tld.cnf \
>   -out www.domain.tld.crt
Signature ok
subject=/C=US/ST=NY/L=New York/O=LOTA-SAN/OU=SANSRUS/CN=www.domain.tld/emailAddress=kyle@SANRUS.com
Getting Private key

cat *.key *.crt > sillysan.pem
```

When I try curl and wget I can't get any noticible differences:

```
time curl -ssl3 --noproxy \* -D - --insecure http://www2500.domain.tld
curl -ssl3 --noproxy \* -D - --insecure http://www2500.domain.tld  0.01s user 0.00s system 69% cpu 0.012 total
```

Results are the same with www vs www2500. I guess it is possible that --insecure bypasses the checking altogether, but for now I'm going to give the standard stamp of a very unscientific test:

[image]